# Myself, my wife, and my daughter Mira

Tags: riddle, steganography

"I have a riddle for you to solve:

I was born in Russia.

My relatives and many of my friends live there.

I just moved here with my wife and my daughter Mira.

Now that I've come this place,

my daughter is very excited.

You're confused already? Now comes the question:"

> "Who am I?"

Comment: First word of every sentence spells out "I'm in my....". Can't figure out where to go from there.

Comment: You are user_194421 on Puzzling;)

Comment: You could be "Who" just read the question from right to left;)

Comment: I is the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You are Andy.
>  
>  Pick alternate end letters of each line.
>
>  "**I** have a riddle for you to solve:
>  I was born in Russi**a**.
>  **M**y relatives and many of my friends live there.
>  I just moved here with my wife and my daughter Mir**a**.
>  **N**ow that I've come this place,
>  my daughter is very excite**d**.
>  **Y**ou're confused already? Now comes the question:"

Comment: Yes, full explanation for bounty. And hide your answer (put >! at the beginning of its line)

Answer (score -1):

> Mira's Father

This, I think is the most logical, and straightforward answer

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! The steganography tag suggests that it's not quite that straightforward - I'd assume we need to find his actual name hidden somewhere in the puzzle. Also, for future reference, answers should be hidden in spoiler tags.